# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Cannot update ''Дата_рождения''; field not updateable."

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oledb

Программа выдает ошибку всвязи с тем, что поле обновить нельзя. Не понимаю почему, пытался разобраться, а Дата_рождения написал в кавычках, т.к. без кавычек читает как Дата рождения. Подскажите, что я могу исправить чтобы кот заработал?

```
            string idСотрудника = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string ФИО = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string idДолжности = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string Дата_рождения = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            string query = "UPDATE Сотрудники SET [ФИО]=@ФИО,[idДолжности]=@idДолжности,'Дата_рождения'= @Дата_рождения WHERE [idСотрудника]=" + dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            OleDbCommand CMD = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idСотрудника", idСотрудника);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ФИО", ФИО);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idДолжности", idДолжности);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Дата_рождения", Дата_рождения);


        }
    }
}
```

upd: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров."[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем использовать русский язык в коде? я понимаю что теперь так можно, но не нужно

Comment: В SQL в одинарных кавычках записывается строковый литерал.

Comment: @AntonNikolaev может он 1С разработчик )